# CRUD Restler Post from Form

Tags: php, html, forms, api, restler

*FIXED***
Turns out my browser was cached! It was working all along. Only update I did to my code was updating the result once the comment is posted so I can get back the info in json response.

```
return $result->comment = array('video_id'=>"$video_id",'fb_id'=>"$fb_id",'comment'=>"$comment");
```

I'm having trouble posting values from a form to restler. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

When I try posting my form I get a return:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
      }
    }
```

**Here is my code for my form(comment.html):**

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/api/index.php/comment" method="post">
    <label>fb_id</label>
    <input type="text" name="fb_id">

    <label>video_id</label>
    <input type="text" name="video_id">

    <label>comment</label>
    <input type="text" name="comment">

    <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Here's the code for my class(comment.php):**

```
    class Comment{
        static $FIELDS = array('video_id', 'fb_id','comment');
        public $restler;

        public function insert($rec){
            $video_id = mysql_escape_string($rec['video_id']);
            $fb_id= mysql_escape_string($rec['fb_id']);
            $comment = mysql_escape_string($rec['comment']);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(video_id,fb_id,comment) VALUES('$video_id','$fb_id','$comment')";
            mysql_query($sql);
            return 'Record Inserted';
        }

        public function post($request_data=NULL){
            return $this->insert($this->_validate($request_data));
        }

        private function _validate($data){
              $comment=array();
              foreach (Comment::$FIELDS as $field) {
                  if(!isset($data[$field]))throw new RestException(417,"$field field missing");
                  $comment[$field]=$data[$field];
              }
              return $comment;
          }

    }
```

If someone can please help, all my other API calls are working great for GET. It's the POST i'm having trouble with.

Comment: This restler https://github.com/danwrong/restler?

Comment: Nope - This restler - http://luracast.com/products/restler/